# add element by 'index'(key) to pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame({'ids':[9,5,7,9,5,9]})
c = d.groupby(['ids'], sort=True)['ids'].count()
>>> c
ids
5    2
7    1
9    3
Name: ids, dtype: int64
```

How can I add an element to this `series` (`c`) with, say, `key` = 6 and `value` = 10 ? The desired output should be:

```
>>> c
ids
5    2
6    10
7    1
9    3
Name: ids, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c.loc[6] = 10
```

Or

```
c.at[6] = 10
```

Or

```
c.set_value(6, 10)
```

Add a `sort_index` to sort by index

```
c.at[6] = 10
c.sort_index()
```

To explicitly drop that into the second position with out messing with ordering otherwise

```
pd.concat([c.iloc[:1], pd.Series(10, [6]), c.iloc[1:]])
```

Comment: Thank you. May I ask, how can you convert these one-liners to accommodate a list/array of indices (all corresponding to the same value) ?

Comment: @Tony you only use loc in this way. c.loc[[6, 7, 8]] = 10

Comment: I asked because when trying this I am getting `KeyError: '[16 17 18] not in index'`. (Python 3.5) -unless these indices are already there, but I am asking about new ones.